# If statement to pull data from excel sheet depending on day of the week

Tags: php, excel

I'm doing a data pull from excel to display the output in HTML via PHP dependent on the day of the week. My code is as follows:

```
$dw = date('N');

if($dw==1) {$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(10);}
elseif($dw ==2) {$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(11);}
elseif($dw==3) {$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(12);}
elseif($dw==4) {$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(13);}
elseif  ($dw == 5) {$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(14);}
$A = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
$B = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
$C = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
$D = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
$E = substr(($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue()), 0, 1);
$F = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
```

The problem I'm having is that instead of getting the data from `sheet 10`, I'm getting the data from `sheet 1`. In fairness even if I change the active sheet number to correspond to a different sheet I still get the same output yet further down the sheet I use a piece of code to pull the date and time from `sheet 0` and this works fine.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHPExcel documentation:

[PHPExcel - Worksheets](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md)

```
getSheet(10)
```

instead of getActiveSheet (which doesn't have any arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setActiveSheetIndex(n) instead of getActiveSheet(n)

Or you could do it like this:

$mySheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($mySheet);